# Add a .css theorem class in marp(it)

Tags: css, markdown, marp, marpit

I would like to incorporate the following CSS classes in my marp slides (I work within vscode with the vscode extension):

```
.theorem {
display: block;
font-style: italic;
}
.theorem:before {
content: "Theorem. ";
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
.theorem[text]:before {
content: "Theorem (" attr(text) ") ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style: |
     .theorem {
display: block;
font-style: italic;
}
.theorem:before {
content: "Theorem. ";
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
.theorem[text]:before {
content: "Theorem (" attr(text) ") ";
}
paginate: true
```

And inside your file you have to add class on block item
https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr